# Joining 3 strings and using them to find element not working

Tags: robotframework

I've a situation in my app where I need to click on file name from a /div table which will save the file name internally and gets displayed in a /div grid. Every time I run the automation, I need to click on a new file.
I don't have any problem in clicking the file to be saved.
But after the click, the app stores the file in a /div grid and I want to select the file that I added.

For this I used this approach:
I am storing the file name in a global variable `${g_ExtractedFileName}`

For eg: **XX_YY_Response_IdNum_48015_2020-07-27T12-18-44.334442.txt**

My complete Xpath to the file is something like this

```
xpath://div[@role='row']//span[contains(text(),'XX_YY_Response_IdNum_48015_2020-07-27T12-18-44.334442.txt')]
```

For this I have the below:-

```
    ${attachedFileXpath1}=  set variable  xpath://div[@role='row']//span[contains(text(),'
    ${attachedFileXpath2}=  set variable  ${g_ExtractedFileName}
    ${attachedFileXpath3}=  set variable  ')]'
    ${attachedFileXpath}=  set variable ${attachedFileXpath1}${attachedFileXpath2}${attachedFileXpath3}
    click element  ${attachedFileXpath}
```

This throws an error

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
> '//div[@role='row']//span[contains(text(),'XX_YY_Response_IdNum_48015_2020-07-27T12-18-44.334442.txt
> ')]'' is not a valid XPath expression.

When I don't use the variables and simply use (hard coded value for file name)

```
click element  xpath://div[@role='row']//span[contains(text(),'XX_YY_Response_IdNum_48015_2020-07-27T12-18-44.334442.txt')]
```

It works correctly.

I also tried this but same error

```
${attachedFileXpath}=  catenate  ${attachedFileXpath1}${attachedFileXpath2}${attachedFileXpath3}
```

I am not sure when the 3 variables are concatenated, it cuts off the variable value to a new line causing this problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to simply use the replace functionality that is already present in Robot Framework variables. The below example will result in an Element not found error, but that is expected.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${g_ExtractedFileName}     XX_YY_Response_IdNum_48015_2020-07-27T12-18-44.334442.txt  

*** Test Cases ***
Use Global String in Locator
    Open Browser    https://google.com    chrome
    click element  xpath://div[@role='row']//span[contains(text(),'${g_ExtractedFileName}')]
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create keyword which accept the file name as argument and returns complete valid xpath expression. It will be re-usable and elegant solution -

```
*** Test case ***

Select file saved in div grid
    ${attached_file_xpath}=   GetAttachedFileXpath    ${File_Name}
    Click Element        ${attached_file_xpath}


*** Keywords ***

GetAttachedFileXpath    [Arguments]    ${File_Name}
   
    return from keyword    xpath://div[@role='row']//span[contains(text(),'${File_Name}')]
```